# Change console initial path after mount /home directory from an ext4 partition

Tags: partitioning, mount, home-directory

I recently followed the [Ubuntu guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving) to move my `/home` directory and mount it from an ext4 partition on the same disk I recently did.

The most important changes and commands I did from the guide where:

1. Rename my old `/home` to `/old_home`

```
cd / && sudo mv /home /old_home && sudo mkdir /home
```

2. Add this line to my `/etc/fstab` file

```
UUID=da22a289-bc25-4109-97a1-3a393e8fe8d5   /home    ext4          defaults       0       2
```

All worked perfectly, however when I open a new console it starts at the path `/old_home/username/` pointing to the security copy I made instead of the one I am currently using at `/home/username/`.

How can I fix this?

**EDIT**

```
$ echo $HOME
  /home/luiscri
$ grep luiscri /etc/passwd
  luiscri:x:1000:1000:luiscri,,,:/home/luiscri:/bin/bash
```

Whole `/etc/fstab` file:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during installation
UUID=b453f406-2885-4273-9321-be8bbb55a76d /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=007A-CCD4  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

# (identifier)  (location, eg sda5)   (format, eg ext3 or ext4)      (some settings) 
UUID=da22a289-bc25-4109-97a1-3a393e8fe8d5   /home    ext4          defaults,uid=1000       0       2
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain exactly what you did. If you followed some guide, then show us the commands the guide told you to run.

Comment: All the commands performed are in the guide link I attached. Besides, I also added  to the question what I think are the most important ones. Thanks for your advise @terdon

Comment: And have you mounted the new partition? Have you rebooted? This sort of thing is why I asked you to tell us what you have run. So we don't need to ask about every step. Also, what is the output of `echo $HOME`? What is the output of `grep username /etc/passwd` (change `username` to your username)? What other lines do you have in `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: Edited the answer with the outputs. I did not rebooted, but I ran the command `sudo mount -a`. I'm also gonna reboot the computer, you may be right and fix the problem @terdon

Comment: That's it. Rebooting solved the problem, the system must still had old dependencies that were not updated by the `sudo mount -a` command. Sorry for the silly answer question @terdon

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand why the guide would say just run `sudo mount -a` when you already have `/home` mounted anyway. But hey, glad you sorted it out! Could you just post a quick answer explaining that rebooting solved the issue and then accept it, so we can mark the question as asnwered?

Comment: Sure, I'm going to post it @terdon

Answer (score 1):

The problem solved by **rebooting the system**.

Although the guide mention it is enough with running the command `sudo mount -a`, it seems there were still old dependencies that were not updated with that command, so after rebooting the system, console initial path changed to the one expected and even the removed files started going to the rubbish folder, and were not removed permanently as it was happening before.